# Idea for no repetition in code with spring hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate

I would like to have an idea so that I will have to make a technique that allows me to ease the spots in the programming (hibernate, spring) so that I activate a single class that applies the methods of CRUD for all objects by changing as the object to avoid repetition of code for each object
a course material or an example on youtube or on paper and thanks in advance

Comment: check about CrudRepository

Comment: Take a look to Spring Data Jpa repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I solved the problem. In this case we can use the generic interfaces (genericity) for which we can use for any entity

For example

```
public interface IProduitDAO<T> {

public T save(T s);

public T findOne(Long id);

public List<T> findAll();

public List<T> findByDesignation(String mc);

public T update(T p);

public void delete(Long id);
}
```